# ValueError in input to CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, shapes

making a model for image segmentation using keras in python but getting error at first layer which is Conv2D. 
In code this line is as:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3, 3),padding='same',input_shape=(1,500,366,3)))
```

but getting following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

I am making this model initially for one image.

Comment: PS: input_shape(samples=1,width=500,height=366,channels=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing your first dimension like this:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3, 3),padding='same',input_shape=(500,366,3)))
```

Comment: try model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3, 3),padding='same',input_shape=(366,500,3)))

Comment: But when I am adding the line model.fit(data,output,batch_size,epochs) it  gives error:   ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_1 to have shape (None, 183, 250, 32) but got array with shape (1, 366, 500, 3).....that is it's giving error on last layer ...
......Maybe error is somewhere else